# How to build a infix TO prefix function using lua

Tags: lua, prefix, infix-notation

I want to create an infixTopostfix function which will take an infix expression and convert it into a prefix expression. I want to know if there are any built-in prefix to infix functions or operators available to help me?

Comment: what do you mean with convert an infix to a prefix expression? do you want to manipulate strings? there is no such thing built in Lua. But there is most likely some code available online or you write it yourself.

Comment: is there built in stack avaliable for lua

Comment: of course Lua has a stack... please use google for such trivial questions. please read [ask] and improve your question. it will be downvoted and/or closed otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Q: Is there built-in stack available for Lua?
A: It is easy to implement a stack in Lua.

```
local stack = {}

local function push(value)
   table.insert(stack, value)
end

local function pop()
   return table.remove(stack)
end

-- Example:
push(42)
push('Yes, Lua has a stack')
print(pop())
print(pop())

--  Output:
-- Yes, Lua has a stack
-- 42
```

Just don't push `nil` to the stack.

Comment: is there built in stack in lua

Comment: Yes, all the local variables are stored in the stack.  Just use the recursion and local variables (function arguments are local variables too) to make use of built-in stack.